# Multiple usage of a dataset in different collcets without populating the dataset several times

Tags: apache-flink

Is there any way to execute different collects over the same dataset without populating the dataset several times in Apache Flink?
I just want to populate dataset once and apply several different collects on that.

The following code, seems to read the data file two times which I want to avoid.

```java
myDataset = env.readCsvFile(..);
DataSet<Tuple3< >> test1 =  myDataset.map(new map1()).filter(new filter1());
DataSet<Tuple3< >> test2 =  myDataset.map(new map2()).filter(new filter2());
List< Tuple3<>> List1 = test1.collect();
List< Tuple3<>> List2 = test2.collect();
// ...
```

Comment: This is not possible. Each call to `collect()` triggers the execution in the cluster from scratch. But what do you mean by "different collects"?

Comment: Simply, I meant different collect executions. To be precise, I have a dataset that I've applied different transformations on. Then I ran the collect command on the different datasets produced in previous step.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to collect intermediate result? As `collect()` copies the data from the cluster to you client I assume that the data set is small. Thus, you could split your job into multiple once, and feed the result of the first collect via `fromElements()` into the next job.

Comment: Dataset is not small I am reading it from a file and do some different transformations and filters, which produces different result dataset. after that I apply collect over each result to produce intermediate result for the next steps.

Comment: Why do you pull the data to the client if the result dataset is large (sound very inefficient)? Can you share the structure of your dataflow program including all collects? Please edit you question.

Comment: I updated the question with a sample code!, I have to collect the data because I need to get some data in specific positions.

Comment: You could union the result data sets before sending them back to the client. Of course, you would have to tag the individual elements to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: Hi @Till, I didn't get what you just said.

Comment: `DataSet<Tuple3< >> unionedTest = test1.union(test2)` and then call `collect` on `unionedTest`.

Comment: Applying union over the two datasets makes the dataset larger than the 10MB restriction of the of collect().

Comment: You can increase the maximum framesize of akka to support message which are larger than 10 MB. Set the config value `akka.framesize: 20mb` in the `flink-config.yaml`.

Comment: akka.framesize parameter is not in the flink-config.yaml file, should I add it ?

Comment: There is not such a parameter and adding it also prevents starting Flink!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using `collect()`. You need to add sinks that do not trigger job execution and start the program explicitly. For example, you could write your results into files:

```java
myDataset = env.readCsvFile(..);
DataSet<Tuple3< >> test1 =  myDataset.map(new map1()).filter(new filter1());
DataSet<Tuple3< >> test2 =  myDataset.map(new map2()).filter(new filter2());
test1.writeAsCsv(<filePath1>);
test2.writeAsCsv(<filePath2>);

env.execute(); // trigger execution
```

Please see the documentation for available sinks: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/programming_guide.html#data-sinks

You need to read the result sets from `<filePathX>` manually into you client application afterwards.

Comment: All of my goal is avoid reading the input file more than one time now, with this method I have to do again redundant work. Another problem is cast Exception org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.DataSink cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: **This will read the input file only once!** And I just updated the code. The assignment to the List is wrong... (was a c&p error from your code example). You need to add additional code, after `env.execute()` to access the result files.